# How to delete all objects returned from a ParseQuery in android?

Tags: android, object, parse-platform

I wanted to know how I can possibly delete all ParseObjects that I get returned from a ParseQuery.
The ParseQuery will have to find all objects that contain a specific String ("keyString") in a specific field ("keyField") as in query.whereEqualTo(keyField , keyString).

Then all the objects than contain that keyString will have to be deleted.

Thank you all in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ParseObject.deleteAllInBackground` and this will achieve what you want. Pass it an array of parse objects.

At this point in time, each object deleted will count as 1 parse request, instead of one single query.

Comment: ok , but how do I do it with the parseQuery so that it deletes only returned object and not all?

Comment: the ParseQuery returns a list of objects you want. Send that list to the deleteAllInBackground. Use the documentation for that

Answer (score 0):

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("ParseObject");
ParseObject.deleteAllInBackground(query.find());
```

something like this